# How to create yammer share button for different logins?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In my script file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s0.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_social_buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">yam.platform.yammerShare();</script>`enter code here`
```

In html page:

```
<span id="yj-share-button"></span>
```

How do I post something from my application to someone's page? Consider it as the scenario where an organisation is conducting some user engaging web event. So if the user clicks on share button, a post should be made from Company's yammer's page to users yammer page.